# php triggers android app to send its gps location

Tags: java, php, android, gps

I am a beginner in java and php.
My application is made of 2 parts:

1. server side (`php`)
2. client side android device (`java`).

Whenever the admin on the server side wants, he can send request to the android for its location coordinates even if the application on android is not running.
I managed to create the java file that will detect the mobile location and save it in a variable on the android.
My question is, how to enable the php(server side) to send request that will start the action of finding the location coordinates on the android?

thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: I think I am supposed to use push notification, but I have no Idea how!

Answer (score 0):

You can add push notification capability to your app using [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, Dongie Agnir for your help But according to my project I am working on, there must be no constraints to end users such as having a google account and as far as i know google cloud messaging require end users to have such accounts.